# How to force child component to reload its data and its view when parent data changes Angular 4

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I am using angular 4. I am a bit new to it although i had used Angular JS.

I have a parent component which has an array of objects

```
people: Person[]; //array of Person model
```

And in the parent component the user modifies people array through its view

Now there is a child component(personComponent) in the parent components view that iterates  through the people array like so

```
<person *ngFor="let person of people; let i = index" [person]="person">
```

The child component shows percentges of each person in the personComponent

```
@Input() person:Person; //person model
percent:number;

ngOnInit(){
    this.percent = this.person.percent;
}
```

Now in the parent component, when a new person is added to the people array, each child component is supposed to have a new percent.

So i created a method in the parent component that calculates the percent of each person

```
setPercent(){
  this.people.forEach((p)=>{
     p.percent = Math.round((p.value/this.total_amount)*100) //total amount is a variable in the parent component
  })
}
```

Now every time a new person is added the setPerson method is called...the problem is that the child component does not update its data and the percent of each person in the people array is not updated.

I have tried using ngOnChanges on the child components person variable but that did not update the child components data and hence the child components view did not change as well. What can i do pls.

Comment: forget "percent" in your children. Not use {{percent}}, just {{person.percent}}

Comment: Eliseo thats correct, that worked i didnt even have to do anything else...Its the same answer that Justinsa gave below...who do i give the correct answer to how does this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Person` component, you take the percentage value on initialization and no longer update it. Instead of doing that, you could use the `person` property, that has the always up to date value. So you should be able to use it as

```
{{person.percentage}}
```

in your template.

Comment: That worked but who do i give the correct answer to cos Eliseo also wrote the correct comment around the same time as yours

Comment: For other people wondering why this does not work, it's because you should make your @Input immutable. When you change `person` in your parent, you actually do not change the object for your child, so the `ngOnInit` is not called.

You should make sure your person is immutable.

Answer (score 1):

On your child component use the following:

```
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  // your selector and template
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
```

and in your parent component try the following:

```
import {ChangeDetectionRef} from '@angular/core';
```

and Inject it in the constructor:

```
constructor(private cd:ChangeDetectorRef){}
```

and in your method that update the percentages:

```
setPercent(){
 this.people.forEach((p)=>{
 p.percent = Math.round((p.value/this.total_amount)*100) //total amount is a 
   variable in the parent component
 });
 // TRY THIS
 this.cd.detectChanges();
 // OR THIS
 this.cd.markForCheck();
}
```

This code will tell the change detection to check of changes on your component and it's children.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the onChanges lifecycle hook.

// Child component

```
import { Component, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes['person']) {
        console.log(changes['person'].currentValue);
    }
}
```